# How can I plot a meshgrid in 2D?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have this code, which takes a meshgrid, and applies a transformation to every point:

```
function [newx, newy] = transform(x, y)
    newx = 10 * x + y*y;
    newy = 5 * y;
end

[x, y] = meshgrid(1:5, 1:5);
[u, v] = arrayfun(@transform, x, y);
```

I want to plot the new mesh in 2D. The closest I can get is to do so in 3D by adding a Z component of 0:

```
mesh(u, v, zeros(size(u)))
```

[image: 3D mesh]

How can I get matlab/octave to just show this plot on a 2d set of axes?

Comment: You can add `view(0,90)` at the end to see the figure right from above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point here, but what's wrong with a simple `plot(u,v,'b-x',u',v','b-x')`?

[image]

Comment: I'm new to matlab, and I have no idea what I'm doing? That does the job, but can you explain what the arguments represent there?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for plot: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/plot.html. First you plot `v` vs `u` in blue colour, with a solid line and a "x" marker at each data point (that's the `b-x` argument). This gives you the "curved" vertical lines. Then, you plot the transpose of `v` (`v'`) vs the transpose of `u` (`u'`) on the same graph, using the same formatting. This adds the horizontal lines to the graph.